# Appending user input array to file [c]

Tags: c, file, append

I'm trying to add a sentence to a text file but I seem to only add one word of the sentence instead of the whole sentence. I know that using fputs("this is a sentence", pFileText); It works just fine with adding text, but not by adding a string variable. What am I doing wrong?

```
char sentence[1000];

FILE * pFileText;

pFileText = fopen("text.txt", "a");

printf("Enter text: ");
scanf("%s", &sentence[1000]);

fputs("\n", pFileText);
fputs(sentence, pFileText);
fclose(pFileText);
```

Comment: `&sentence[1000]` is a pointer to one element *beyond* the end of the array.

Comment: Also, `scanf("%s", ...)` will read only one word. You can read entire lines (up to and including the terminating new-line character) with `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", &sentence[1000]);
```

will be

```
scanf("%s", sentence);
```

Enable compiler warnings and run the same code. It will tell you where you went wrong.

```
gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c
```

The second example is passing an `char*` but first one is attempting to pass an `char(*)[1000]`. `scanf`'s `%s` format specifier expects a `char*` not `char(*)[1000]`.

`fegts` is the correct alternative here I would say, and much cleaner to use.

```
fgets(sentence,1000,stdin);
```

with a check of return value of `fgets` would do the job you want to achieve here. (You wanted to read a line and `fgets` does that).